# Centering a skewed predictor variable in a multilevel model that is involved in an 2-way interaction

Tags: regression, interaction, multilevel-analysis, skewness, centering

Is there a correct method to center (mean or median centering) a skewed predictor variable in a multilevel model? The predictor is a skewed, count variable and will feature in a two-way interaction with a binary predictor (primary interest for the study). In most multilevel models, centering continuous predictors is commonplace when dealing with interactions, but I'm not sure if this is appropriate with a highly skewed positive predictor.

I have found the following links on crossvalidated, but they don't quite address my question completely:

[https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/216195/centering-skewed-predictors](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/216195/centering-skewed-predictors%20which%20suggests%20that%20median%20centering%20is%20also%20appropriate.%20%20%20https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/171381/is-it-right-to-scale-and-log-transform-a-variable-in-a-lmer/171382#171382) which suggests that median centering is also appropriate.

[https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/171381/is-it-right-to-scale-and-log-transform-a-variable-in-a-lmer/171382#171382](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/216195/centering-skewed-predictors%20which%20suggests%20that%20median%20centering%20is%20also%20appropriate.%20%20%20https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/171381/is-it-right-to-scale-and-log-transform-a-variable-in-a-lmer/171382#171382)